# how to extract an @value from XML file in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I have the following structure in an XML file:

```
 <current>
        <city id="2510170" name="Triana">
            <coord lon="-6.02" lat="37.38"/>
            <country>ES</country>
            <sun rise="2016-04-04T06:04:05" set="2016-04-04T18:50:07"/>
        </city>
        <temperature value="290.92" min="288.15" max="296.15" unit="kelvin"/>
        <humidity value="93" unit="%"/>
        <pressure value="1009" unit="hPa"/>
        <wind>
            <speed value="8.2" name="Fresh Breeze"/>
            <gusts/>
            <direction value="230" code="SW" name="Southwest"/>
        </wind>
        <clouds value="90" name="overcast clouds"/>
        <visibility/>
        <precipitation mode="no"/>
        <weather number="501" value="moderate rain" icon="10d"/>
        <lastupdate value="2016-04-04T10:05:00"/>
    </current>
```

The question is how to extract the temperature ( @value ) using XPATH of Python ?. That is, extract from "290.2" of the following line:

```
 <temperature value="290.92" min="288.15" max="296.15" unit="kelvin"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that root reffers to `<current>` node

```
from lxml import etree

xml_file = 'test.xml'
with open(xml_file) as xml:
   root = etree.XML(xml.read())

temperature_value = root.xpath('./temperature/@value')[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simply do

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('path_to_your_xml_file')
temperature = root.find('.//temperature')
```

Now temperature.attrib is a dictionary with all of the info

```
print temperature.attrib['value'] # 290.92
print temperature.attrib['min'] # 288.15
print temperature.attrib['max'] # 296.15
print temperature.attrib['unit'] # kelvin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for temp in root.findall('temperature'):
    print(temp.get("value"))
```